# We sign on a power of attorney or We write a power of attorney

Tags: idiom-request

If there are two people that are going to notary in order to give one of them a power of attorney, then what's the idiomatic way to refer to it?

> We are going **to write** a power of attorney.
>
> We are going **to sign on** a power of attorney.
>
> We are going **to** **do** a power of attorney.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> We are going to sign a power of attorney. <sup>normal/neutral</sup>
>
> We are going to do a power of attorney. <sup>informal: **do** = execute; **do** could also mean "draft"</sup>

The following:

> We are going to write a power of attorney.

would mean something like *draft language for the document known as a "power of attorney"*.